# Increase dialup connection speeds

Tags: cisco, router, dialup

I'm currently manage a p2p dialup network like this:

client computer==(ethernet)router Cisco 2500==(async port)modems----pstn----modem==dial-in server

All things run well except the connection rates between the client and server is only 9600. Anything above 9600 ain't stable, and require countless of retries to make a connection. But due to QoS, **I must maintain the rate is at least 19200**.

So how to achieve this? I checked the line quality, it's OK and can product good quality voice call. Do I need to check modems and cables?

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy, replace all the phone side cables.  The serial cables between modem and router/dialin server are not related.  If you have other modems to try, try them.  But I doubt this is your problem.

More likely...is one side or the other on a PBX or VOIP or other digital phone system?  If so, you may be at the limit.  These systems are not designed to handle modem traffic.

If this is the case, your best recourse is to get a POTS line installed.  Or, perhaps, to pony up for a real connection, although I understand in some cases the modem dialup may be preferable.

Comment: Yes, due to the old system requirement, I need to maintain the p2p dialup connection like this. I'll try your suggestion. If you know any tips or tricks about these dialup things, feel free to tell me. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Make sure you are using good hardware based modems.  External connection via Serial port means you have one.  Some PCI modems are too, but most are "soft modems."  USR brand is a good bet. (2) One thing that will help speed up the initial connect time.  Figure out how to disable 56k mode(s) (X2, V.90, V.92).  These require that one end be a "digital modem" with a digital connection to the phone network (e.g., ISDN or DS1).  If you know you don't have that, it just wastes time to try.  For USR modems, the AT command ATS32=224 will do this.

Comment: The modems are made by Hayes, which are good I guess. For the 2nd suggestion, I'll try it but I think this is quite difficult since the router handles almost everything about the modems and left nothing much for me to tweak the connection. But your info is useful anyway. Thank you :D

Comment: Just so i'm clear, the benefit of disabling 56k mode is that the connection will come up faster after dial.  If the connection is long-lived it is probably not worth the bother, but if it comes up and down a lot it may really be helpful.